# Spring boot static content include profile properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a static webpage in my Spring boot project which has this line:

`<redoc spec-url='http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs'></redoc>`

How would I make this dynamic based on the profile properties, I imagine it would be something along the line of this, but I cannot find any documentation online:

`<redoc spec-url='${url}'></redoc>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you'll need to use a templating engine (like Thymeleaf) for this.

[Here is an article](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc#thymeleaf-in-spring-boot)

Basically, you add the starter to your Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

(Use the version matching your Spring Boot version)

If you just want to insert values from a properties file containing key-value pairs, the Spring Boot starter will automatically configure that.

Then you create a file `messages.properties` in your resources folder and in your HTML you add this template: `<span th:text="#{welcome.message}" />` which would display the value of `welcome.message` in the messages.properties file.

[Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) also allows more complex templates.

Comment: You don't need to specify a `MessageSource` Spring Boot already configures one which does exactly what you configure.

Comment: Its not a must to have template engine, its just the most convinient way.

Comment: Oh, is there a way to use SpEL oder some other message interpolation for static resources @Antoniossss? Would you share some details, I'm curious.

Comment: You can intercept resource request and filter it manually, at least this is how I done it in the past

Comment: OK, this does seem less convenient :)

Comment: Yes, but somethimes it is the ONLY way. For example, I had enchance to swagger.html with some javasript(html itself comes from included jar, so it is "readonly") and stuff and the only way I came out was using request filter. It took 10 lines of code, so not that bad.

Comment: I've got Thymeleaf working but it's looking for message.properties, how do I get it to look at application.properties etc?

Comment: @Callum you should _definitely_ **NOT** use application.properties for that, because this contains, well, application configuration which you could leak to the outside world by accidentally using the wrong key in your template.
The linked article describes configuring a `messageSource`, there you can set a name. I would recommend you to keep application.properties and your messages separate!